# Table data doesn't reload in UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, loadview

This code works: `[self.tableView reloadData]`, but if I extend the `loadView` method of `UITableViewController` like this:

```
- (void) loadView {
    [super loadView];
    float headerHeight = 80;
    UIView *tableV = self.tableView;
    CGRect tableFrame = self.tableView.frame;

    self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
    [self.view release];

    tableFrame.origin.y += headerHeight - [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    tableFrame.size.height -= headerHeight;
    tableV.frame = tableFrame;
    [self.view addSubview:tableV]; 
}
```

the tableView data isn't reload. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a UITableViewController, self.view == self.tableView, so in line 7 (`self.view = [[UIView...`) you're actually replacing both self.view and self.tableView.

If all you want is to move the table view down, try using contentInset.

Comment: yes, self.view == self.tableView, but after super method i change it.

Property self.view store reference to another object (i checked it)

Ewerything look fine, but not reload Data

Comment: self.view points to your newly created UIView, but self.tableView is null.